# Display items in a listview

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hi i would like to know how can i display one column of my sqlite database into a list fragment 
How can i modifiy this to display it into the list :

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase db;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(rollno VARCHAR,name VARCHAR,marks VARCHAR);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student VALUES('hello@aol.com', 'Jeff', 'Bath');");

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listarray);

        ArrayList<String> getList()
        {
            ArrayList<String> tempArrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
            myDataBase = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student", null);
            //  Toast.makeText(myContext, ""+cursor.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    tempArrayList.add(cursor.getString(2)));

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            return tempArrayList;
        }

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListViewEx extends ListActivity {
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        listView = getListView();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListViewEx.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(rollno VARCHAR,name VARCHAR,marks VARCHAR);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student VALUES('hello@aol.com', 'Jeff1', 'Bath')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student VALUES('hello@aol.com', 'Jeff2', 'Bath')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student VALUES('hello@aol.com', 'Jeff3', 'Bath')");
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student", null);
        //  Toast.makeText(myContext, ""+cursor.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                arrayList.add(cursor.getString(1));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: And here how can i choose to show only the seconde column for example

Comment: So i define like this ? SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                cursor,
                new String[] {"1"},
                new int[] {R.id.textView1}

Comment: What correponds the listarray in the adapter ?

Comment: arraylist come from the methed getList() methed

Comment: Because getList() cannot be a resolved variable and also same problem for get readable database .

Comment: its is the party of database class not an activity class

Comment: Yes but like i said i dont create a  database in another file i use everything in my main activity